# Problems deleting emails using Python and Imap

Tags: python, email, automation, imap, gmail-imap

I am having some trouble deleting emails using python3 and imap4. So far I have been able to successfully retrieve and display emails based on tutorials I have found online. Whenever I follow ones that show how to delete emails, none of them have worked. The method I have seen used the most looks like this:

```
mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(self.server)
mail.login(self.email, self.password)
mail.select("inbox", True)
typ, data = mail.search(None, "ALL")
for i in data[0].spit():
    mail.store(i, '+FLAGS', '//Trash')
mail.expunge()
mail.close()
mail.logout()
```

I don't receive any errors when the code is run. From what I understand, it should delete all the emails in my inbox. When I go and check it, all my emails are still there. What am I doing wrong? Oh, and I'm using gmail if that makes a difference.

Comment: What is data[0].spit() in for i in data[0].spit():? Doesn't that give you an error?

Comment: @ThaerA oh that’s supposed to say split() In my actual code it is spelled correctly.

Comment: Try mail.store(i, '+FLAGS', ''\\Deleted'') instead of mail.store(i, '+FLAGS', '//Trash')

Comment: Thanks, but it still didn’t delete the emails.

Comment: What is your server software?  What does your protocol trace look like?

Comment: Are you using Gmail? If so, why not use the [Gmal API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/trash)?

Comment: You can try high level lib: https://github.com/ikvk/imap_tools